# Image.FromFile internal error

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to load an image file saved with the jpeg extension to a variable.
When I try to get a jpeg from a folder in my project, I get this message:

> ```
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile returned  Internal error retrieving local value.
> ```

I can't get my head around this problem, although I searched for solutions on MSDN and other sites.

This is my retrieving code:

```
 var filename = @"D:\Kay\ASP.NET MVC\ImageToDatabase\ImageToDB\src\ImageToDB\wwwroot\images\imgFromDisk.Jpeg";

Image img = Image.FromFile(filename);
```

I am working in ASP.NET Core.

Installed:

> Install-Package CoreCompat.System.Drawing -Version 1.0.0-beta001 -Pre

To get the Image.FromFile method to exist.

Tell me if theres anything more you wish to see.

Comment: Have you tried updating the packing to beta006?

Comment: Updated to Beta006. Same result